# How can I prove that $\left (\dfrac 1f \right)''(x) = -\dfrac {f''(x)}{f(x)^2} + 2\dfrac {f'(x)^2}{f(x)^3}$

Tags: calculus

I think its need some theorem what idk. Can someone help me?

$$\left (\dfrac 1f \right)''(x) = -\dfrac {f''(x)}{f(x)^2} + 2\dfrac {f'(x)^2}{f(x)^3}$$

Comment: maybe try rewording the question, adding more context, and showing us your attempt (or at least what theorems you are looking at ) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:
$$(f^n)'=nf^{n-1}f'$$
And the derivative of a product of two functions is :
$$(fg)'=f'g+fg'$$
Now you can differentiate twice
$f^{-1}(x)$.